# Parse dynamic URL through tabula-py as file source

Tags: python, amazon-s3, tabula

I'm using a tabula-py to parse presigned url of a pdf dynamically saved on s3 bucket.

This is what I have tried so far.

```
url = s3_client.generate_presigned_url(
    ClientMethod='get_object',
    Params={'Bucket': 'xxxxxx', 'Key': keyName,},
    ExpiresIn=60,
)

tabula.convert_into(f'"{url}"', "output.csv", output_format="csv", pages='all',  stream=True)
```

When I copy directly the link to tabula-py as "https://link", the file is processed. How can I make tabula process url as "http://url"?

Also this did not work `tabula.convert_into(url, "output.csv", output_format="csv", pages='all',  stream=True)`

Comment: why u need it as http: ?

Comment: I just need to access it without downloading it. Whether as https link or s3//:  path. But as a dynamic url path